# Nz in MAX aggregation function SQL access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a little lost here I need your help. Can I use `Nz` in aggregation function?
For example:

```
Nz(Max(Some table), Default_Column)
```

I got my SQL Query here. you probably won't understand the names.

```
SELECT Equip.id_equipamento, Calib.id_calibração,
       Nz(Max([Registo de Calib].[DateRealization]),[Calib].[Date Activation]) AS [Last Date],
       Calib.Tip
FROM Equip
    INNER JOIN (Calib INNER JOIN [Registo de Calib] ON Calib.id_calibração = [Registo de Calib].id_calibração) ON Equip.id_equipamento = Calib.id_equipamento
WHERE (((Equip.id_equipamento)=[Calib].[id_equipamento]))
GROUP BY Equip.id_equipamento, Calib.id_calibração, Calib.Tip;
```

The error it gives is the same as when I use aggregation function without `group by`.

Any ideas?

The deal here is If a column I selected with `max` is empty or null, it will get the value from `calib`'s column `date activation`. I needed this to make a calculated queries with dates.

Comment: It should work if you put `[Calib].[Date Activation]` into a Max() aggregation as well.

Comment: I think it works! Just doing some tests with data and see if the query is "user fault proof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Nz(Max([Registo de Calib].[DateRealization]), [Calib].[Date Activation])
```

will (rightfully) complain that `[Calib].[Date Activation]` is neither in an aggregate function nor in the Group Gy clause.

So the solution is to aggregate it as well:

```
Nz(Max([Registo de Calib].[DateRealization]), Max([Calib].[Date Activation]))
```

Comment: Can I use another column on that  SELECT with this? : DateAdd("m",Calib.MonthInterval,Calib.[Date Activation]) As [Next Date]
Giving the same error. I might need use Max in another column here on dateadd.

Comment: It's a general rule. If you use Grouping in a query, **every** column in the SELECT list must either be aggregated, or in the GROUP BY list. This includes your [Next Date] column. It doesn't matter if it's a calculated column.